# How to replace all matched patterns below a matched tag in a file

Tags: sed, tags

Let's assume the following file:

```
blah
blah blah
blah blah blah
string
blah blah blah blah
#####TAG#####
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah
string
blah blah
string
blah
```

The goal is to replace all 'string' below the TAG (and only those) with 'another_string' so that the file becomes:

```
blah
blah blah
blah blah blah
string
blah blah blah blah
#####TAG#####
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah
another_string
blah blah
another_string
blah
```

The line numbers of all 'string' cannot be predicted.

Obviously, if I use the basic sed command, all 'string' are replaced:

```
sed 's|string|another_string|g' file
```

Any suggestion?
I'm open to other tools as well such as perl.

Comment: Good question with proper sample data, required output and code! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a range address with `sed`:

```
sed '/TAG/,$ { s/string/another_string/g; }' file
```

The `/TAG/,$` part is a [range address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Range-Addresses) that starts at the first line matching the regexp TAG and end at [the end of the file `$`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Numeric-Addresses). The part between the curly braces is the substitution command that should be applied to all lines that fall within the specified range.

Answer (score 2):

This will better fit as a task for `awk` (will be very lightweight because it process only one line at a time):

```
$ awk '/#TAG#/{f=1} f{sub(/string/, "another_string")}1' file
blah
blah blah
blah blah blah
string
blah blah blah blah
#####TAG#####
blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah
another_string
blah blah
another_string
blah
```